# Django says - No module named 'blog'

Tags: python, django, installation, python-module

I am getting `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog'"` error when  add my blog app to the INSTALLED_APPS section of `settings.py`. I have determined that it has something to do with the way I have added the "blog" app under INSTALLED_APPS. When I remove the 'blog' reference from `INSTALLED_APPS` error goes away. It looks like that `Django` is unable to find directory for my blog app?

I have done one thing differently and that is use:

```
python manage.py startapp blog /myproject
```

Difference here is specifying the `/myproject` directory and not using:

```
python manage.py startapp blog
```

Which will place it under root directory `myproject`. I wanted to avoid adding app directory in the root folder so i stay more organized. But it looks like Django does not like this or i am not referencing this correctly in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section?

My project directory is as following:

```
myproject/
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

Inside my `settings.py` I have setup my app `blog`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]
```

Comment: because your app is in `my_project` module, I believe you should write `my_project.blog` in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of simply `blog`.

Comment: Thank you that did the fix it.

Comment: i have same problem , if it work properly in admin section ,but problem on when i add my_project_name.blog nothing work

Comment: Agreed with Vincent, using `my_project.blog` worked. Have to remember that this will work according to where `manage.py` is located.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django needs to be able to import your application, usually this means including the full path relative to the root directory `'myproject.blog'`.

You could add `<full_path_to_your_project>/myproject/myproject` to `PYTHONPATH` so that you can import `blog`, but I would not recommend it

Comment: Thank you that did the resolve it, so lesson here is if using non standard Django structure  is to include full path to the app.

Comment: I would not say your directory structure is unusual. If you can run `import my_app` from a shell then you can include it as an application

Answer (score 20):

Directory structure is unusual. More usual and the one that matches your app being named blog would be

```
myproject/
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

Comment: that is the right way. modules and site folder must stick together

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by adding the path of the app in the **settings.py** of myproject in this below format

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'blog.apps.BlogConfig', # <app_name>.apps.<class_name>
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue .Turns out I had already registered my app in the settings.py before running 'python manage.py startapp #myapp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I usually add the config path to installed apps to avoid this problem. So installed apps would look like this:

```
NSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog,apps.BlogConfig',
```