# Django Static Files No module named <app_name>

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a Django app and I deployed it online but I am running into some problems with the static files. When I run the collectstatic command it says 'There is no module named '. I have looked at the questions on here and none of them answer my question.

My static files were stupidly put into the apps specific directory, however I moved them out and tried to run it when they are in the right directory but still no luck.

It is really strange:

**Settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ticketr', # App name
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/django/ticketr/static'
# Tried it at: '/home/django/django_project/django_project/static'
# Also tried it at: '/home/django/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Directory**

```
   .
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── django_project
    │   ├── db.sqlite3
    │   ├── django_project
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.py
    │   │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.pye
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   │   └── wsgi.pyc
    │   └── manage.py
    ├── images
    │   ├── event_images
    ├── media
    │   ├── images
    │   └── qrcode
    ├── qrcode
    ├── templates
    └── ticketr
        ├── admin.py
        ├── admin.pyc
        ├── apps.py
        ├── forms.py
        ├── forms.pyc
        ├── helper.py
        ├── helper.pyc
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.pyc
        ├── media
        │   └── images
        │       └── event_images
        ├── migrations
        ├── models.py
        ├── models.pyc
        ├── static
        │   ├── css
        │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
        │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
        │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
        │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
        │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
        │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
        │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
        │   │   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
        │   ├── fonts
        │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
        │   ├── images
        │   │   ├── background1.png
        │   │   ├── event_images
        │   │   ├── logo.png
        │   │   └── qr.jpg
        │   └── js
        │       └── bootstrap.min.js
        ├── templatetags
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── __init__.pyc
        │   ├── ticket_extras.py
        │   └── ticket_extras.pyc
        ├── tests.py
        ├── urls.py
        ├── urls.pyc
        ├── views.py
        └── views.pyc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically my problem was a couple of things. I setup a new droplet and started again and I got it to work:

1. My app was in the wrong directory. It must be within the django_project directory in the same directory as the manage.py file.
2. As stated above I had to alter my STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT
3. Once thats done I had to restart gunicorn and refresh the static files using:

   python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

   NB. Make sure that the application is in the same directory as the django_project. home/django/django_project <- there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `STATICFILES_FINDERS` to the [default setting in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) - that's what finds static files within your apps. Your static files are appropriately located in the `/static/` folder within your app, so you can delete your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting.

You'll probably want to add a `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#static-files) as well.

EDIT: You also have a weird directory structure. It should look more like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963237/2532070 - with `ticketr` directory inside the first `django_project` directory, at the same level as `manage.py`.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. I added the static file finders, I don't think I need them because django.contrib.staticfiles is already included. But I changed the static root to the directory where it is in my app and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkBarrett `STATIC_ROOT` should be a new directory, like `./static/` where your files get collected...not where it's collecting the static files from. Collectstatic finds static files in all the directories you specify, and collects them in one place.

Comment: @MarkBarrett I'm guessing the issue is my edit, your directory structure.

Comment: Yea that fixed it. It collects the static but all of the static files are 404

Comment: @MarkBarrett that's a separate problem, but the best solution is probably looking at what the URL is that is a 404 and making sure your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` work together to point the files there.

Comment: Yea not sure why I'm getting the 404. Very confused about the whole thing because I deployed a second app and never had this problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142119/discussion-between-mark-barrett-and-ypcrumble).