# why ImportError: No module named blog showing when trying to execute commannd from blog.models import Post in python shell?

Tags: django, python-2.7

```
ImportError: No module named blog
```

Above error showing while trying to execute following command in python shell
Command used :

```
from blog.models import Post
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django says - No module named 'blog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963141/django-says-no-module-named-blog)

Comment: You need to have a directory named blog containing a file named models.py on your python path for this to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a django-app called blog and it should added in the list of Intalled apps in settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

Add **blog** to **INSTALLED_APPS** in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'yourapp',
]
```